# PHP find next open day

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a SQL table with open times. It stores day of week, open time, close time and closed

My question is, in PHP how would I work out the next day of the week a shop is open from today's day of the week?

Hope that makes sense.

Table

[image]

PHP Code

```
foreach($value->openTimes as $time){
                if($time->open_day == strtolower(date("l")) && $time->closed != 1){
                    $daySet = 1;
                    $value['next_open'] = 'Today';
                    $value['next_open_start'] = $time->open_start_time;
                    $value['next_open_end'] = $time->open_end_time;
                    break;
                }

                //IF ITS NOT OPEN TODAY FIND THE NEXT NEARESR DAY IT IS OPEN
            }
```

Cheers

Comment: please provide sample data of the table. it sounds like something that can be done in the sql query itself

Comment: See creating a [mcve].

Comment: show what you have done so far

Comment: Added example, thanks

Comment: @parpar Added example

Comment: Do you want something like if day is closed, show nearest open date ?

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about doing this ?

```
$days = [
    'Today',
    'Tomorrow'
];

foreach ($value->openTimes as $time) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
        if ($time->open_day == strtolower(date('l', strtotime("+$i day"))) && $time->closed != 1) {
            $daySet = $i + 1;
            $value['next_open'] = !empty($days[$i]) ? $days[$i] : date('l');
            $value['next_open_start'] = $time->open_start_time;
            $value['next_open_end'] = $time->open_end_time;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The moment when you added this condition `$time->closed != 1`, closing date is already skip if I'm not wrong

Comment: How would this work for the example that today is Fridays but the next day a shop is open is next wednesday